# Why does the $k$-th invariant factor of some matrix depend only on the first $k$ columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ integral matrix and $\xi$ an integral vector of dimension $n$. Let $$W_i=[\xi,A\xi,\ldots,A^{i-1}\xi]$$ for each positive $i$. Let $d_{i,j}$ (where $1\le j\le i$) denote the $j$-th invariant factor of $W_i$. It seems that $d_{i,j}$ only depends on $j$, that is $d_{j,j}=d_{j+1,j}=\cdots=d_{n,j}=d_{n+1,j}=\cdots$. By Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, we know that   $W_i$ is equivalent (in $\mathbb{Z}$) to $[W_n,0_{n\times (i-n)}]$ for $i>n$. Thus we only need to consider the case that $i\le n$.

For example, let
\begin{equation*}
    A=\left(\begin{matrix}
2&2&3&3\\
    1&3&0&0\\
    3&3&0&3\\
    0&0&3&2\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right),\quad
\xi=\left(\begin{matrix}
1\\
    2\\
    3\\
    0\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right)
    \end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
    W_1=\left(\begin{matrix}
1\\
    2\\
    3\\
    0\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right),
W_2=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&15\\
    2&7\\
    3&9\\
    0&9\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right),W_3=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&15&98\\
    2&7&36\\
    3&9&93\\
    0&9&45\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right), W_4=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&15&98&682\\
    2&7&36&206\\
    3&9&93&537\\
    0&9&45&369\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right)
    \end{equation*}
The Smith normal forms of these matrices are
\begin{equation*}
    \left(\begin{matrix}
1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right),
\left(\begin{matrix}
1&0\\
    0&1\\
    0&0\\
    0&0\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right),\left(\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
    0&1&0\\
    0&0&3\\
    0&0&0\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right), \left(\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&3&0\\
    0&0&0&9090\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right)
    \end{equation*}
For a fixed $j$, why  these $j$-th invariant factors of  $W_i$'s are all the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Smith normal form of $W_i$ using [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).  In this way, if you do this, let us say, to $W_4$, for instance, you start eliminating from the first columns, so you are doing a Gaussian elimination to $W_j$, $j<4$.

Please see [Algebraically-nice general solution for last step of Gaussian elimination to Smith Normal Form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612449/algebraically-nice-general-solution-for-last-step-of-gaussian-elimination-to-smi) and [Computing the Smith Normal Form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133076/computing-the-smith-normal-form) on Math.StackExchange, and find more searching for ["\(A\)  Smith Normal Form"](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28A%5C%29%20Smith%20Normal%20Form) on SearchOnMath.

Comment: The string `\(A\)` is treated as bracketed by (uselessly) escaped parentheses:  \(A\).  I assumed you wanted the slashes to appear in the rendered output, in which case you have to escape *them*, too:  \\(A\\) `\\(A\\)`, and edited accordingly.  I hope that this was correct.